# Actionscript 3, parsing giant tables of external data into usable arrays

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, external, txt

I have a basic understanding of AS2 and AS3. I previously tried creating giant arrays in my file so that I could compare arrays against each other, but it would be far better to have the data tables as external files since there is so much of it. If I want to scale up my analysis, there are millions of entries in total. Ideally I can click a button and then it only loads in the part that is needed. All data is meant to be static in their files. If the data needs modifying, I'll do it manually in the text files.
The way I set up tables are vertical. EX:

---

Year 1:

Name: Person 1,  Person 2, Person 3, Person 4

Q1: 25, 22, 21, 14

Q2: 14, 25, 19, 33

Etc.

Year 2:

Name: Person 1, Person 2, person 3, Person 4

Q1: 21, 15, 11, 6

Q2: 8, 35, 22, 9

Etc.

---

I have found multiple suggestions on here for parsing txt files, but I remain unclear on how to pull in a table like this and turn it into an array. In this case, Name array would be [Q1, Q2,...]. Person 1 would be [25, 14,...] Since the array is nested, it would only contain data from Year 1. If I can get the basics of this working, the rest is just converting all my tables to txt files and just grinding through.

A bit more background: I'm using Flash to help visualize data since I can draw and do color changes easily in it. There are probably better software out there. I think I'm going the right direction, but if I'm making big mistakes in my assumptions, please correct me. There's other suggestions on here for other formats and methods, in theory the data could be put directly into another flash file as an array and included when needed, that might also work. Once again, I have a smaller scale of this working with the arrays just straight in Flash, it's just going to eventually die if I try and scale up. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Hello and welcome to **StackOverflow**. Please elaborate on this: "*it only loads in the part that is needed*" as it is not clear, what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks for welcoming me. :) As in the example of nested tables, if I'm looking at Year 1, I don't need Year 2 data at the same time. 50,000 entries is enough. Normally I could split files Year 1, Year 2, etc, but it's more convenient to have fewer, but longer files. (I originally coded everything using AS2, currently looking into using the method of including .as files to hold the tables. Seems to be working, but might have downsides I've not considered.) AS3 allows other formats, but will be butt to migrate to since it doesn't do OOP. But hey, I'll do what I gotta do to make my stuff work.

Comment: Ok, got it. First of all, I **strongly** advise to switch to **AS3**, both for data format support and for processing performance (you are going to process huge chunks of data and in certain cases **AS3** is 100 times faster than **AS1/2**). Then, I'd do the following. Load the whole dataset (it's just a few Mb worth of text, nothing fancy). Scan it to create an index of years, with **RegEx** you can even afford not to control case-sensitivity or extra/missing spaces, like "year1:" or "YeAr  5  :". Upon need, extract the substring by the year number and work with it, then dispose all the data.

Comment: Right, I'll fuss with the AS2 a bit longer to see if I can optimize it better. It was taking 5 seconds to chunk through the data which is wayyyy to slow. (I was comparing arrays about 3000 elements long, several other steps involved). Probably I'll learn AS3 because speed is definitely important for getting timely analysis. The main thing still unaddressed is coding to read the nested table and then convert the columns into arrays. Previously I was using libreoffice to make my arrays and porting them into Flash, but leaving them as columned tables would save a looot of time on preparation.

Comment: **AS3** is not that different from **AS2** to be *learned*. The syntax is the same, but **AS3** does things a bit differently — in much more consistent way.

Comment: I'd run MS Excel with its visualizer tools to analyse a couple of tables, anything larger and you're looking for some serious analytic stuff. AS3 is about drawing initially, and not about complex analysis anyway, the data manipulation is best run elsewhere, you can use your existing Flash app to display the results and send requests with altered parameters, but calculation is best handles elsewhere.